# FCM invalid topic name. Base64 generating string with invalid char

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating an app that's subscribe users to FCM topics. This topics in many cases have a special chars in yours names. Thereby I'm converting this topics names into base64 string like this:

```java
    byte[] data = myText.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    String converted = base64.replace("\n","");
```

In many cases the above code works perfectly. But there are some cases where the base64 function generates strings like this: "**UHJvcHJpw6E=**". The **equal** symbol is not allowed in FCM topics name. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry for asking! I solved this issue changing `Base64.DEFAULT` to `Base64.NO_PADDING` in android and using this function in php `$topic = base64_encode($_POST['topic']);
$topic = str_replace('=','',$topic);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the [documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/OldFiles/sdk/android-sdk-linux/docs/reference/android/util/Base64.html) the **NO_PADDING** flag should fix the problem.

> int    NO_PADDING  Encoder flag bit to omit the padding '=' characters at the end of the output (if any).

```
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_PADDING);
```

For a better understanding check [Base64 documantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).